# What is the reasoning for using ADF test with trend or drift?

Tags: time-series, trend, augmented-dickey-fuller

When people carry out ADF tests they are mostly preparing a time-series for analysis (in an ARIMA, VAR or whatever model).

In that case I fail to understand why one would use tests with trend. If you carry out an ADF with trend, I understand it *roughly* as if you would remove the trend and then test unit root in fluctuations around that trend. If that is so, you would still have to de-trend/difference your data for your model (to avoid spurious regressions, etc.).

Could anyone tell me if my thinking is correct? If not, why would one use such tests?

Comment: I do not see what exactly you find confusing. Are you asking why you cannot remove the trend first and then proceed with ADF and further modeling instead of ADF (allowing for trend), trend removal and then further modeling?

Comment: No, not exactly. Many people test their series for unit roots using ADF with trend. However, if they reject the null using this specification, they still cannot use in an ARIMA model, right?

Comment: If they think there is a deterministic trend (which is why they specify the ADF test with a trend), then they have to account for the trend either before estimating an ARIMA model (thus in a stepwise manner) or within ARIMA (i.e. specify a model which is ARIMA+trend and estimate both simultaneously).

Comment: But it is correctly understood that if one find that the series is trend (or drift) stationary, one would still have to difference/de-trend before being able to work with it?

Comment: Trend-stationarity implies that differencing is a bad idea, because by differencing you create a unit root in the moving-average part of the model. As I indicated above, you can detrend within a model (simultaneously) or before (stepwise).